# how to insert different querys answers into a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, multiple-insert

I'm trying to insert some dates into a table. I know how to insert values if the dates are statics, I mean "4", "car", "1456", etc,  and I also know how to insert one query answer into a table, but I don't know how to do it when I want to insert the answers of more than one query.

I want to insert into the restaurant table two values:

```
insert into restaurant (id_restaurant, id_category)
```

These values are the answer of two querys.

```
select id_rest from restaurant_menu where name = "discount" 
select id_cat from category_menu where name = "beach";
```

How I can insert into id_restaurant and id_category,  id_cat and id_cat respectively?

Please, could you help me? I have searched for this many times but I haven't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the Cartesian product inserted?

```
INSERT INTO restaurant (id_restaurant, id_category)
SELECT id_rest, id_cat
FROM restaurant_menu rm, category_menu cm
WHERE rm.name = "discount" AND cm.name = "beach";
```

Comment: Thanks @AgRizzo. I'm not sure if I want Cartesian product. Are there any another way to do this?